# Cannot install Kali linux

Tags: installation, kali-linux

I am trying to install Kali Linux. My laptop is 64-bit. I am trying to use bootable USB drive. It is giving me this error saying "An installation step failed, You can run the failing item again from the menu or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is: Install the system." I am really new to Kali Linux. I use mint. It has never happened to me before. I don't know what to do. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest moving the question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ but also adding some more detail to the end of the question, it is probably un-answerable as is.

Comment: why should i move it to unix.stackexchange? kali is a linux distro, and what else do you want to know that might help you?

Comment: Answer to first part: yes kail is a gnu+linux distro, and so a Unix system. http://unix.stackexchange.com if for all Unixes, including Gnu+Linux. Answer to 2nd part. I have no idea.

Comment: Some tail'ed system logs would make it easier.

Comment: How are you trying to install Kali, via text mode or graphical mode?  Are you running the install from the boot menu in Kali, or are you booting the live system and trying to install from the install to hard disk option you get after the distro boots?   What program are you using to copy the ISO to a USB thumbdrive?    You are not very clear in regards to where exactly in the process you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your usb is corrupted. How did you make the usb? (i.e. dd, UNetBootin, Pendrive linux). I recommend dd you use dd like this: dd if=/dev/your_usb of=/path/to/iso bs=512k (if on mac, bs=1m)

Hope this helped!!

!Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the ISO file?
 It is possible you have a corrupted download.
Check the real SHA256 hashes from the Kali Linux website, and check if the output is similar to:

```
sha256sum (kali linux iso file name).iso
```

You should use the dd command to write your ISO to the drive, if that's an option.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/path/to/kalilinux.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M   (where X is the letter shown from `lsblk` or `parted -l`
```

If that doesn't work, check if any ISO can be installed from the USB drive.
Kali may not work on your system for certain reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Like most people said, it's posibly due to a corrupted USB drive, bad image burning process, etc. Go and download, again, a fresh Kali Iso. Then use another thumb drive and burn it using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), since the first use, I swear by this nifty tool. Now reboot and install.

Answer (score -1):

I have a really working solution if you are trying to install in virtual box.
I also tried a lot and visited a lot of forums, just **Increase disk space to *20GB*** while choosing size for vdi.

Comment: And what happens then?